# How to use "promptAsync" from expo-auth-session, old library used in video tutorial was deprecated

Tags: react-native, expo, google-oauth, google-api-js-client, appauth

I have been following the tinder 2.0 react native tutorial https://youtu.be/qJaFIGjyRms At 1:04:00 he sets the sign in method to: "await Google.logInAsync()" but I have noticed the google app auth library used in the video is now deprecated, I am redirected to use expo auth session instead but I notice there is a slight difference, where they used "await Google.logInAsync()" I must put "promptAsync" instead, when I do this I get the error promptAsync is undefined, I try with google.loginasync and get the same error that it is still undefined, what should I do? screenshot [image: first screenshot]

code:

```
    import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react'
    //import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
    import * as Google from 'expo-google-app-auth';

    const AuthContext = createContext({});

    const config = {
        androidClientId: 
        '236293699216-9a0nknjdq7ie79h40iubg0tddokgogfv.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        iosClientId: 
        '236293699216-6jdpm0rd6kn5d0qlbh1vgva5afgbqgib.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        scopes: ["profile", "email"],
        permissions: ["public_profile","email", "gender", "location"],
    }

    export const AuthProvider = ({ children}) => {
        const signInWithGoogle = async() => {
            await Google.logInAsync(config).then(async (logInResult) => {
                if (logInResult.type === "success") {
                    // login
                }
            });
        };

      return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
          value={{
          user: null,
            signInWithGoogle
        }}
        >
          {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      )
    }

    export default function useAuth() {
        return useContext(AuthContext);
    }
```

I sought help on the forum that belongs to the maker of the video and other people had come across the same issue, one person recommended to go into package.json find the installed dependencies and change “expo-google-app-auth” from “^10.0.0” to “~9.0.0” and then npm I in the terminal, I have done this and I'm now getting the error “no such file or directory /Users/shangefagan/twinder-3/node_modules/expo-google-app-auth/node-modules/react-native/package.json” I have changed it back to “^10.0.0” but still getting the same error, screenshot
[image: screenshot of console]
do I just npm uninstall expo-google-app-auth and try to use expo-auth-session as I was originally trying? if so What is the correct way to use promptAsync from the expo-auth-session library

I check the docs for both libraries, expo google app auth: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v43.0.0/sdk/google/ and expo auth session: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/ but I am unsure exactly how to use the new login method "promptAsync"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `promptAsync` you have to use the package `expo-auth-session`. Like you said `expo-google-app-auth` is deprecated.

Comment: Ok, and do I just npm uninstall expo-google-app-auth to stop the deprecated library error showing up?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay. DM me if you need more help.

Comment: Okay I will dm, I have updated my code and I can't tell if the login method is working as it simply redirects past the google login back back to the homepage

Comment: I don't know how to dm edit: please dm me instead

Comment: I can't find the option neither. This is my email: anas.gharrab@gmail.com.

Comment: Great, I’ve sent you an email

Answer (score 0):

first screenshot
code:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react'
//import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import * as Google from 'expo-google-app-auth';

const AuthContext = createContext({});

const config = {
    androidClientId: 
    '236293699216-9a0nknjdq7ie79h40iubg0tddokgogfv.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    iosClientId: 
    '236293699216-6jdpm0rd6kn5d0qlbh1vgva5afgbqgib.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    scopes: ["profile", "email"],
    permissions: ["public_profile","email", "gender", "location"],
}

export const AuthProvider = ({ children}) => {
    const signInWithGoogle = async() => {
        await Google.logInAsync(config).then(async (logInResult) => {
            if (logInResult.type === "success") {
                // login
            }
        });
    };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
      user: null,
        signInWithGoogle
    }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).